# How to Disable System beep in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, hardware

I have been getting the beep beep sound from my system on startup onwards,
i have tried

`sudo modprobe pcspk`  (gives an output `modprobe: FATAL: Module pcspk not found.`)
  and edited

`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file and add `blacklist pcspkr`
.Also done the same for `snd_pcsp`
by `modprobe -r snd_pcsp` and added `blacklist snd_pcsp`

But noting works for me .The Beep sound seems to the Hardware error and is there any way to disable it, i have gone through many posts but nothing happens

Comment: These "beeps" usually have some meaning. Try searching what they mean before disabeling it in BIOS. Error code description example: http://www.pchell.com/hardware/beepcodes.shtml

Answer (score 0):

System beep sounds on boot usually are **not controlled by Ubuntu** (or any other OS). In most BIOS we have beep codes to indicate hardware issues on boot which will be played on a tiny speaker on the motherboard.

Some BIOS allow configuring the internal speaker, e.g.:

[image] [image]

On a desktop computer we can also physically remove the beeper from the motherboard:

[image] <sub>[Wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8c/PC-Speaker_IMG_9311-9312.JPG/320px-PC-Speaker_IMG_9311-9312.JPG)</sub>

Note that after disabling the internal speaker we may no longer be able to hear errors on booting.

Comment: is a there any way similar to http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-system-beep-windows-7-8 can be done in ubuntu

Comment: @ArUn the beep at startup has nothing to do with Windows. Even if you disable Windows beep like that it'll still beep at startup